# Can't download Excel file from server using Web Service C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I want to download Excel file on Client's machine.
I'm using Web Service C#.
Using JQuery AJAX call I'm calling Web Service and then I want to download excel file.

But the issue is when I'm running Web Service directly in the browser it's downloading but with AJAX call it's not downloading.

Here's my Code:

C#:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void DownloadExcel(string fileName)
    {
        string filePath = "~/Report/" + fileName;

        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.Buffer = true;
        Context.Response.Charset = "";
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ";");
        Context.Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        Context.Response.Flush();
        Context.Response.End();
    }
```

JS:

```
    var FileName = "Test.xlsx"

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { "fileName": FileName },
        url: "API/MyService.asmx/DownloadExcel",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
              $('#MessageModal').modal('show');
        },
        error: function (request, error) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ajax request is probably downloading the file, but the browser is not interpreting it as a file download (because with ajax calls, you are handling the response yourself)

Here is a sample page, solving your issue old-school.

Please note the use of a `<Form>` element with `id="excelDownloadForm"` on the page. It does not have the `runat="Server"` attribute.

After Asp.Net, we are accustomed to having only one form (runat="Server") per page. But actually, you can have multiple forms in your HTML page and can post different bunches of data to different endpoints.

The only drawback here is that you cannot handle the successful response and show a modal when the transfer completes.

Please let me know what you think of this approach and if it helps.

(Note: Fully tested and working)

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="excelDownloadForm" action="API/MyService.asmx/DownloadExcel" method="post" target="_self" >
        <input type="hidden" name="fileName" id="fileName" />
    </form>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <script>
            var FileName = "test.xlsx"
            $("#fileName").val(FileName);
            $("#excelDownloadForm").submit();
        </script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank u so much. It's working fine. But I want callback function on submit. If file downloaded successfully or not and show message in modal

Comment: The end-user will see the downloaded document, I don't know why you need to show a modal window, what does the message tell the user?